# Replacement for JWebUnit / HttpUnit

Tags: java, testing, continuous-integration, web-testing

We've used both JWebUnit and HttpUnit in the past to do functional tests of web applications. Both of them seem to have issues in handling javascript. We are not particularly interested in testing the javascript at this point, but JWebUnit and HttpUnit tests have broken since we added some small Ajax components (Dojo Date / Time pickers for instance) to our pages.

Selenium and Watir do not fit because they essentially drive browsers and we are running these tests from CruiseControl on a box where we are not allowed to install a browser.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Canoo's WebTest](http://webtest.canoo.com/webtest/manual/Downloads.html) is pretty good and can handle what you're looking for.

Comment: AFAIK both Canoo WebTest and JWebTest use HtmlUnit underneath. Both use the Rhino JS engine, too. Somehow I suspect that the results will thus be similar.

Answer (score 2):

You want [HtmlUnit](http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/).

It isn't perfect browser emulation (for that you need a browser driver) but it has significant javascript support. Check out the [introduction to testing your JavaScript](http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/javascript-howto.html).

Answer (score 0):

Go with Canoon. Canoon is built upon HtmlUnit, and was previously built upon HttpUnit.

yc

Answer (score 0):

> [Celerity](http://celerity.rubyforge.org/) is a JRuby library for
>   easy and fast automation of web
>   application testing. It is a wrapper
>   around the HtmlUnit Java library and
>   is aimed at providing the same API and
>   functionality as Watir.